# Show component for each dynamic div in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, render

I'm trying to render a component HomeScreen.js for dynamically generated div's. I'm able to get this somewhat working, but I'm not able to get the component separated from the dynamically generated div, furthermore I'm only trying to render HomeScreen.js for only the div that is clicked, but the functionality I have currently opens HomeScreen.js for All divs.

(This is a contact app, the dynamically generated divs are contacts. I'm just trying to show contact information for each contact that gets clicked)

I've attached screenshots of the current functionality and of the functionality I'm trying to get

[image: Current Functionality]

[image: Desired Functionality]

I could use some insight.

```
import store from '../libs/store.js';
var jsforce = require('jsforce');

class menuScreen extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        const data = store.getState();

        this.state = {

            username: '',
            messages: data.messages,
            records: [],
            showModal: false,
            showChat: false

        }
    }

    handleSearch(e) {
        this.setState({
            username: e.target.value
        })
    }

    handleChange(evt) {
        this.setState({
            username: evt.target.value.substr(0, 100)
        });

    }

    onClick(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            showChat: !this.state.showChat
        })
    }

    onLinkClicked() {


        var conn = new jsforce.Connection({
            serverUrl: 'https://cs63.salesforce.com',
            accessToken: sessionStorage.getItem('token')
        })

        var parent = this.state.username
        //console.log(this.state.username)
        conn.sobject("Contact").find({
                LastName: {
                    $like: parent
                }
            }, 'Id, Name, Phone, Account.Name'

        ).sort('-CreatedDate Name').
        limit(5).skip(10).execute(function(err, records) {
            if (err) {
                return console.error(err);
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
                var record = (records[i]);
                console.log("Name: " + record.Name); 
                console.log("Phone: " + record.Phone);
                console.log("Account Name: " + record.Account.Name);

            }
            this.setState({
                records: records
            })

            this.setState({
                showChat: !this.state.showChat
            })

        }.bind(this))

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='menubox' id='menubox'>

                <div className="boxbox">
                    <input className="search" type="text" placeholder="Contact Last Name" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.username} />
                    <input className="submit" type="submit" onClick={this.onLinkClicked.bind(this)} value="GO" /></div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        {this.state.records.map(record => (
                            <div className="info-block block-info clearfix">
                                <div className="square-box pull-left">
                                    <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-user glyphicon-lg"></span>
                                </div>
                                <h5>{record.Name}</h5>
                                <h4>{record.Phone}</h4>
                                <p>{record.Account.Name}</p>

                                    **//Trying to render home.js when Chat Bubble is clicked.**

                                    <a onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>
                                    <img src="./img/speechbubble.png" className="textIcon" />
                                     {this.state.showChat && < HomeScreen / >}
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        ))}
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        )
    }

}

export default menuScreen;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason is, you are using single `state` variable to control all the `dynamic div`, you need to use an `array`, each value for each element, So instead of `showChat = false`, use `showChat = []` in `state` variable. To change the values of `array` in `onClick` function you need to pass the index of element in `onClick` function and use that index to change the specific value.

For other changes check the code and comments, it should work.

Use this:

```
import store from '../libs/store.js';
var jsforce = require('jsforce');

class menuScreen extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        const data = store.getState();

        this.state = {
            username: '',
            messages: data.messages,
            records: [],
            showModal: false,
            showChat: []  //initially blank array
        }
    }

    handleSearch(e) {
        this.setState({
            username: e.target.value
        })
    }

    handleChange(evt) {
        this.setState({
            username: evt.target.value.substr(0, 100)
        });

    }

    onClick(i, e) { // pass the index on item clicked
        e.preventDefault();

        let showChat = this.state.showChat.slice();
        showChat[i] = !showChat[i];  //use that index to change the specific value
        this.setState({ showChat })
    }

    onLinkClicked() {

        var conn = new jsforce.Connection({
            serverUrl: 'https://cs63.salesforce.com',
            accessToken: sessionStorage.getItem('token')
        })

        var parent = this.state.username
        //console.log(this.state.username)
        conn.sobject("Contact").find({
                LastName: {
                    $like: parent
                }
            }, 'Id, Name, Phone, Account.Name'

        ).sort('-CreatedDate Name').
        limit(5).skip(10).execute((err, records) => { //use arrow function
            if (err) {
                return console.error(err);
            }
            // this loop is not required
            /*
            for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
                var record = (records[i]);
                console.log("Name: " + record.Name); 
                console.log("Phone: " + record.Phone);
                console.log("Account Name: " + record.Account.Name);

            }
            */
            console.log('recoreds values', records);
            this.setState({
                records: records,
            })
        })

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='menubox' id='menubox'>

                <div className="boxbox">
                    <input className="search" type="text" placeholder="Contact Last Name" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.username} />
                    <input className="submit" type="submit" onClick={this.onLinkClicked.bind(this)} value="GO" /></div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        /*use the index also in map*/
                        {this.state.records.map((record, i) => (
                            <div className="info-block block-info clearfix">
                                <div className="square-box pull-left">
                                    <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-user glyphicon-lg"></span>
                                </div>
                                <h5>{record.Name}</h5>
                                <h4>{record.Phone}</h4>
                                <p>{record.Account.Name}</p>

                                   <a onClick={this.onClick.bind(this, i)}>
                                    <img src="./img/speechbubble.png" className="textIcon" />
                                     {this.state.showChat[i] && < HomeScreen / >}
                        {/*use this.state.showChat[i] specific value*/}
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        ))}
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        )
    }

}

export default menuScreen;
```

**Suggestion**: Instead of binding method in render, define the binding in the constructor, like this:

```
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
```

Use direct by:

```
onChange={this.handleChange}
```

Comment: Thank you. This was immensely helpful! One question, how can I open 
< HomeScreen />  outside of the parent menubox container?

Comment: didn't get you, from a parent component of menubar ?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to show homescreen outside of menubar

Comment: sorry, don't know about that.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mayank's answer about using an array for `showChat`, but building on that idea, is there any reason why you couldn't make each contact a separate component? Personally, I would render an array of child components, like a Contact component or something, and pass props to each of them from the state in the outer menuScreen component.

```
class Contact extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {}
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="info-block block-info clearfix">
        <div className="square-box pull-left">
          <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-user glyphicon-lg"></span>
        </div>
        <h5>{record.Name}</h5>
        <h4>{record.Phone}</h4>
        <p>{record.Account.Name}</p>

        <a onClick={this.props.onClick}>
          <img src="./img/speechbubble.png" className="textIcon" />
          {this.props.showChat && < HomeScreen / >}
        </a>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And then you can use it in your menuScreen component like so:

```
import store from '../libs/store.js';
var jsforce = require('jsforce');


class menuScreen extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        const data = store.getState();

        this.state = {
            username: '',
            messages: data.messages,
            records: [],
            showModal: false,
            showChat: []
        }
    }

    handleSearch(e) {
        this.setState({
            username: e.target.value
        })
    }

    handleChange(evt) {
        this.setState({
            username: evt.target.value.substr(0, 100)
        });

    }

    onClick(i, e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        let showChat = this.state.showChat.slice();
        showChat[i] = !showChat[i];
        this.setState({ showChat })
    }

    onLinkClicked() {

        var conn = new jsforce.Connection({
            serverUrl: 'https://cs63.salesforce.com',
            accessToken: sessionStorage.getItem('token')
        })

        var parent = this.state.username
        //console.log(this.state.username)
        conn.sobject("Contact").find({
                LastName: {
                    $like: parent
                }
            }, 'Id, Name, Phone, Account.Name'

        ).sort('-CreatedDate Name').
        limit(5).skip(10).execute((err, records) => {
            if (err) {
                return console.error(err);
            }
            // this loop is not required
            /*
            for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
                var record = (records[i]);
                console.log("Name: " + record.Name); 
                console.log("Phone: " + record.Phone);
                console.log("Account Name: " + record.Account.Name);

            }
            */
            console.log('recoreds values', records);
            this.setState({
                records: records,
            })
        })

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='menubox' id='menubox'>

                <div className="boxbox">
                    <input className="search" type="text" placeholder="Contact Last Name" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.username} />
                    <input className="submit" type="submit" onClick={this.onLinkClicked.bind(this)} value="GO" /></div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        {this.state.records.map((record, i) => (
                          <Contact onClick={onClick.bind(this, i)} showChat={this.state.showChat[i]} />
                        ))}
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        )
    }

}

export default menuScreen;
```

May be more of an opinion than just an answer, but it's usually better to separate presentation from state in components. That way it's also more extensible because the child Contact component can still do other actions before running the `menuScreen` component's `onClick` function, makes it almost like a decorator.